# How to use for loop through childNodes?

Tags: javascript, nodelist, child-nodes

I need to set z-index dynamically on every node inside div (first node - 1, second - 2, etc). When I'm trying to use the "for" loop on childNodes, I got an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'zIndex' of undefined". Can you please point out my mistake?

You can see the codepen: https://codepen.io/pen/

HTML + JS:

```
<div id="blog__images" class="blog__images">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

```
    var images = document.getElementById('blog__images').childNodes;
for (var i = 1; i < images.length; ++i) {
    images[i].style.zIndex = i;
}
```

Comment: `childNodes` includes the (empty) text nodes between elements. Use `.children` instead.

Comment: And FYI, `console.log(images[i])` would have revealed this problem *immediately*

Comment: `for (const child of node.childNodes) { child.style.zIndex = ... }` is a lot easier to read/write than using a numerical index, `i`. Read more about [for..of syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whitespace inside elements is considered as text, and text is considered as nodes. Those text nodes should be skipped.

```js
var images = document.getElementById('blog__images').childNodes;
// console.log(images);
for (var i = 1; i < images.length; ++i) {
    if (images[i] && images[i].nodeType != 3) {
      console.log("My node:" + images[i].nodeName);
      images[i].style.zIndex = i;
     } else {
      console.log("Skipping Extra node:" + images[i].nodeName);
     }
}
```

```html
<div id="blog__images" class="blog__images">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the structure like this.

```js
var images = document.getElementById('blog__images').childNodes;
for (var img : images) {
    images[img].style.zIndex = img;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the z-index using `.style` and the iteration of `i` on each of your elements in your loop. Example below in snippit...

`images[i].style.zIndex = i;` will do the trick. I have selected the elements directly using the classname, no need for `childNode`...

You can open your browsers console and check the CSS properties for each node after you run the code.

Console for the snippit below once run:
[image]

```js
let images = document.getElementsByClassName('image');
let imgZIndex;
for(let i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
imgZIndex = images[i].style.zIndex = i;
console.log(imgZIndex)
}
```

```html
<div id="blog__images" class="blog__images">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If there are other images on the page outside of the parent class `blog__images`, this will change the zIndex of those elements too, which may have unpredictable results.